# Adding colours to Vega tooltip keys

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

I am trying to get to grips with Vega charts. I have created a chart with multiple line series, and I want to style a Vega tooltip so that the colours of it's key/value pairs match the colours of the various series in the graph.

For instance, with [this example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/interactive_multi_line_pivot_tooltip), I would like the tooltip keys to be consistent with the colour of the keys in the legend.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using CSS, may try something like this to set the colors

```
#vg-tooltip-element tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  color: #96abc7
}
```

Comment: I think a CSS solution is the only way to do it for now, hopefully they add out-of-the-box support for it in a future update. Thanks!